# Table rate for each Category

Tags: magento-1, table-rates

Is it possible in Magento to use table rate for each category products?

I need each of the catergory products use different table rates with different prices and destinations
If possible let me know how I can do this?

Very Thanks

Comment: It's not possible out of the box I'm afraid.  Would you like to get extension name that does this or code snippet to start with?

Comment: please, I would like to know how this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension meets your needs: http://www.webshopapps.com/us/shipping/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html

This article has some ideas on how to make a module that could do this as well: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module